# How to find out Excel Data Connection Query

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a Excel (someelse's Excel) and try to find out the query it is using to pull data from a database. From the data connection properties tool, I see the "Definition" tab, and from that, I see the connection string. It is using MSOLAP. But In the "Command text" it has only one line: SSDB - MktData.

There is no query. How can the Excel pull the data from the DB? I am puzzled.

Thanks for any help.

Jennifer

Comment: Sounds like it is using a stored procedure.

Comment: I see. I will check if it is a stored procedure.

Comment: No it is not stored procedures. It is something very complex, some cubes.